# Proving a complex function is not differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a function of $z=x+yi$:

$$f(z)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^3(1+i)- y^3(1-i)}{x^2+y^2}, &\quad z\neq 0\\
0,&\quad z=0.\end{cases} $$

How do I prove the function is not differentiable? I tried taking limits from the right and the left; I get them to be $y$ and $-y$ but is this enough? All my classmates seem to have got different conclusions.

Comment: Use Cauchy - Riemann equations.

Comment: i should have mentioned this is the question but i have to prove that the derivative doesn't exist at z=o i have the C-R equations and they hold at 0 would i have to show the partial derivatives are not continuous at 0?

Comment: Are you sure it's $-y^3(x-i)$ and not $-y^3(1-i)$? I ask because the latter is a standard example.

Comment: you are correct oops

Comment: The easiest way would be using Cauchy-Riemann equation. I guess you were trying to show that one of it's partial derivatives is discontinuous. If you could show that then answer would be yes, it suffices. (Why?)

Comment: @AidenBhe The CR equations hold for this function - that's the point of this exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold. So if $f$ isn't differentiable at $0$, it must be that one of its components isn't differentiable at $0$.

The function $v : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ describing the imaginary component is

$$v(x,y) = \begin{cases}\frac{x^3 + y^3}{x^2+y^2} & (x,y) \ne (0,0) & \\ 0 & (x,y) = (0,0)\end{cases}$$

At $(0,0)$, the partial derivatives exist, $v_x = v_y = 1$. Now take the directional derivative of $v$ in some other direction, for example $(1,1)$. What do you notice?

> **Lemma:** If $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ is differentiable at $a$, then for every direction $h \in \mathbb R \setminus \{ 0\}$ the directional derivative $D_h f(a)$ exists. Moreover, writing $h = (h_1, \ldots, h_n)$, we have that
> $$D_h f(a) = \sum_{i=1}^n h_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a) $$

If we take $h = (1,1)$ and apply to $v$ at 0, then **supposing $v$ is differentiable at 0** we would have:

$$D_hv(0) = h_1v_x + h_2v_y = h_1 + h_2 = 2$$

But if we actually compute this derivative,

$$D_hv(0) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t} \frac{t^3}{t^2} = 1 \ne 2 $$

By contradiction, $v$ cannot be differentiable at 0.

Comment: $v_x = v_y = 1/2$ ?

Comment: @user1042713 I might be wrong, but I computed $v_x = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t} \frac{t^3}{t^2} = 1$. I'm writing $v_x$ and $v_y$ to be partial derivatives in the $x$ and $y$ directions here.

Comment: im unsure if ive seen this lemma in my studies im gonna lokok through my notes thank you

Comment: @user1042713 What kind of course are you studying? For me I did Complex Analysis after two Real Analysis courses. If you haven't seen this lemma, have a look at differentiation in higher dimensions - it is important for CA!

Comment: i just started doing complex analysis this is my first question sheet on the topic ive done differentiation in higher dimensions but the course where i did that didn't go into directional derivatives much

Comment: @user1042713 Perhaps you have seen this result and I've just gone overkill on the notation. All I'm saying is that directional derivatives are linear, so if you add two directions then then you can just add the two directional derivatives.

Comment: thanks for the help i think i have it